# Having issues installing ruby gems after latest OS X El Capitan update

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubocop

After the latest update it appears a few of my gems have been affected and are either missing/changed.

In particular the gem 'rubocop' is giving me issues as I use atom for a text editor and I have flags popping up.

> "Failed to spawn command rubocop. Make sure rubocop is installed and on your PATH"
>
> "Error: spawn rubocop ENOENT"

I've tried re-installing the rubocop gem through the command line and I'm running into this issue:

`gem install rubocop
Fetching: rainbow-2.1.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/rainbow-2.1.0.gem`

I've even tried to uninstall the gem but there's no output after running `gem uninstall rubocop`

I really have no idea where to begin to resolve this and I'd love any help possible!

Comment: Normally you can't install any gems without `sudo` permissions, or you must use a tool like [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or [`rvm`](http://rvm.io/) to provide an alternative.

Comment: oh my it's been so long since i've needed to use sudo that I had forgotten - that solved it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that installing things into the system Ruby requires `sudo` privileges, `/Library` is usually restricted access.

Installing your own personal Ruby with `rvm` or `rbenv` avoids all this.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you add `sudo` before `gem install rubocop`
And  then go to  documentation of *rubocop* to check which version  of ruby  it takes to run.
You can also install `rbenv`.its better then `rvm` ***(they are ruby version managers your can put multiple versions of ruby on same machine using them)***
if further you need help .. let me know !

happy coding